# Spring Input certain format in jsp file

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, validation

Hello everybody i have a simple question, is there a way in Spring 3.0 MVC formatting an input. 
Here is an example: 
i have a jsp page that has an input like below

```
<th><spring:message code="label.hmerypogr" /></th>
```

is there a way this input to have a certain format  like F.../..../... and when the user type numbers the dots to fill up(but the format keeps the same)?? 
As an example when the user press 4545555666 the input will hava F454/5555/666.

Please help me i stack here long time. Thank you very much!

Comment: That is not an input... But no, there is no such facility in Spring MVC. You will need to write it using JavaScript on the client side. Should be pretty simple though.

Comment: ok then, can you give me a way to do it in javascript then? thank you very much!